# How to read mapped registers on serial port in python

Tags: python, pyserial

I have a hardware connected to COM1 of the computer. The hardware collects status, of switches (Boolean), voltages (4 bytes double value), currents (4 bytes double value) and frequency (4 bytes double value) from an electrical circuit. the data then is mapped to the output serial port which is connected to COM1. Here is the addresses of registers:
F808h,bit 0 (switch status)
F808h,bit 14 (switch status)
F809h,bit 0 (switch status)
F809h,bit 14 (switch status)
F80Ah (current)
F80Ch(current), ....
How can I read these registers?
I used Pyserial but the following result has been gotten:
b"\xa5F`\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xc0\x00\x01\x00\xf8\x00\x00&\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00@\x01@\x00>\x830V>\x834\x96>j#\xe1B\xedS\xf6B\xed\xb7\x0bB\xf9g4Bp\x04\x07>7'\xa4>2\xc2[>*\xb8\x93C\x00E\xa6B\xf9\xf1\x90B\xf6*XBp\x08\xf4R\xd3\n"

I could not interpret it.

To make it more clear, there is an external device that has 16 serial ports. Different IEDs could be connected to each serial ports (ports 1-15) of the device and port 16 is connected to COM1 of the PC. Data of all other ports are mapped to port 16. The following figure shows how the data are mapped to port 16.
[image]

I want to get access to registers of port 16 of device directly in Python. Using readline() or read() methods in Pyserial is not a good idea because I do not need to read all data and in most cases I need to read a specific data or write to specific data. 
Is there any input buffer for mapping data from device to the computer? If yes, then how these buffers can be accessible in Python?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Code answer ? NO ! `binascii.hexlify(answer)` now you got `hex array` not `byte array`,  convert any data with index easily.

Comment: @dsgdfg Thanks a lot for your response. I'm also wondering how the exact register with the defined address can be accessed. For example a user can set the address of the current on 0Ah while the other can use 022h. So, I want to access the same here. How?

Comment: Why don't write device model and brand ? You know data pattern, index multiply by `2` if convert to `binascii.hexlify(answerr)` if want work document base index need  use `struct.unpack('what_incoming',parts)`

Comment: @dsgdfg The device is not a well-known device. It is a SEL Communication Processor (SEL-2032) used for SCADA system in electrical substations> I used it in our Lab for researches and I need to read data of each IED connected to the SEL-2032 continuously. Data is updated every 1/60 second. Also, I do not need to read all data. Just a part of data is required.

Comment: You necessarily need to know what the protocol device is communicating over. The serial port is just a transport layer - a method to send and receive data with the device. The protocol that the device implements will determine what information you need to send in order to interact with the device (i.e. read registers). Pyserial only lets you send and receive over a serial port.

Comment: Serial got a pattern on query/answer. You requested what ? Serial isn't free protocol and **need ask  to device producing company**.

Comment: @theorifice I supposed that serial port is based on a kind of standard protocol that is wrong. I need to understand the company protocol. Thanks for your response.

Comment: @dsgdfg Thanks for your time. You're right. I need to understand the protocol used by the company